# How can I have a raid and a separate OS drive on server

Tags: boot, bios, raid

I am working on re-purposing a server for a pet project. The server has 3 HDDs and 1 SDD. I would like the 3 HDDS to be RAID0 and then install the OS on the SDD.

I'm running into an issue where we setup the RAID in UEFI, and then I boot to USB to install the OS (SecurityOnion). In the OS install, I see the Raid and I see the SDD. I install on the SDD just fine.

On reboot, I get the EFI Shell. I boot back to BIOS and I cannot see the SDD in the boot menu. I tried moving around between Legacy and UEFI (and performing OS installs in both modes) but no matter what I do, the SDD does not appear in the boot menu.

When I reset the defaults, it looks like we are back in Legacy boot mode and I can see all 4 drives in the boot menu. I'm unsure what I need to do to get the raid enstated in such a way as to where I can still boot separately to the SDD.

Any help is appreciated!

Additional Details:

BIOS Version SE5C610.86B.01.01.0022.

Chassis - 1U Eclipse Server
Board - Manufacturer: Intel - S2600WTTR - G92187-272
Product - Eclipse-V4

Comment: Please specify the exact brand/model of the server (you can edit your question to add that information). Without more information this can't be answered as this is highly specific to the exact model of server. The Bios version is only useful if you also tell us which model of server it belongs to.

Comment: Updated with additional server information.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that is a brand of server that I'm not familiar with. Best guess: SSD isn't included in the boot-order in the Bios. Or the server can't boot from SSD at all. (Some servers have SSD just as cache, not to be used as a regular disk and therefore not bootable.. The manual should tell you if that is the case for your server.)

Comment: I can boot to the SSD. For instance, if I reset BIOS to defaults (which breaks apart the array) I can boot to the SSD in legacy mode.

Comment: So it works in Legacy... Ok. That leaves just 2 possibilities: 1 EFI and Legacy have each their own notion of bootable devices. SSD isn't included in the EFI one. You will have to change that in the EFI bios. 2 SSD is ONLY bootable in legacy mode (which would be very odd), so you need to configure the system to run in EFI mode with CSM support (which enables booting of legacy only devices).

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have fixed the issue for me was changing Raid Drivers. By default, Intel (R) ESRT2 (LSI*) was selected. I instead selected the secondary option of Intel (R) RSTe. When I switched to using this raid driver, I was then able to see both the raid and the individual SSD.